# How to connect MongoDb Altas to mondoDb Compass?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I am trying to connect `MongoDb Altas` to `mongoDb Compass` through the connection string provided by the MongoDB Altas after creating a cluster and pressing on connect. I have installed MongoDb Compass but it is not connecting to the mongoDb every time I press connect or enter connection string on mongoDb compass it shows `error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017`

Comment: You might not be adding correct URL to the compass.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your connection string again .
There you will find  inside your string . you need to replace that with your origin password . That's it

```
mongodb+srv://akash:<password>@cluster0.9xphp.mongodb.net/test?authSource=admin&replicaSet=atlas-jfxtq8-shard-0&readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=true

mongodb+srv://akash:yourPasswordGoesHere@cluster0.9xphp.mongodb.net/test?authSource=admin&replicaSet=atlas-jfxtq8-shard-0&readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=true
```